# How does s3's getBucket api implemented?

Tags: amazon-s3

You can have unlimited objects in an Amazon s3 bucket, and use a [getBucket API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html?r=6295) to list your objects. The funny part is you can use any character as a delimiter(like "/" in Linux file systems). With large quantities of objects, how could the S3 API respond in real-time?  You cannot expect a full scan, right? What are the technologies behind s3 storage architecture?

Here is some of my search work results so far. Anyone know any more detail?

1. [s3 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564223/amazon-s3-architecture/727976)
2. [amazon architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415360/what-types-of-technologies-does-amazon-com-use-internally/415365)

Comment: There are several design decisions that could avoid the usage of a full scan, such as indexes, or a simple [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), for example.

Comment: you'r right Viccari, the index part is the most challenging one. Note it's not just a prefix issue, many records with a common prefix but differ in after-delimiter-part have to be skipped in order to list a _"folder"_. This _skip_ process could introduce additional overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding as an answer because there is not enough room in the comments section:

There are several design decisions that could avoid the usage of a full scan, such as indexes, or a simple prefix tree, for example.

Even though several S3 client apps will list prefixes as folders, there is not such concept in S3. Within a bucket, all files are hierarchically in the same level. The organization of the files is in a key/value fashion, rather than in a tree fashion (like one would expect in a "folder"-like system). Please see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder/9330600#9330600) for more information. So, if you want to list your "folders", yes, it is likely that you will need to list your prefixes, i.e. get objects based on prefix and skip the ones having additional information.

Comment: Thanks Viccari. Sure, it's kv fashion with s3 file's namespace, i'm curious of the s3 architecture part, how did s3 did this: you could use any string as the delimiter and the total file number is unlimited. Take this example dataset: folder1/[level2]/[level3], we have one million level2 each with one million level3, and do a ls with prefix=folder1/ and delimiter=/, all [level3] would be folded up. This is a real challenging work to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid full search with an index on the bucket name. I did an experiment regarding this in MySQL. MySQL only really supports B-Trees for this application, which isn't a perfect solution, but should give a significant speed up. I created the following table and populated it with all the files under /usr/ on my system (446594 files):

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dirname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=446722 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 \ 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The result is significant.

```
mysql> select count(*) from files where filename like "/usr/lib/%" \ 
and filename regexp "^/usr/lib/[^/]*";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    68678 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.21 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from files where filename regexp "^/usr/lib/[^/]*";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    68678 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.06 sec)
```